# ¿Leer variables desde archivo de configuración? Laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, configuración

Estoy automatizando un desarrollo bastante grande para que se pueda replicar y solo configurar.

El punto es que cambio las contraseñas de los servicios. Pero quiero agregar ahí también los nombres de las paginas que no son muchas.

Como lo hago con los servios es con la función **"env()"** en en las vistas no puedo hacer esto.

```
<title>{{ env('landing') }}</title>
```

O esto

```
<title>{{ config::get('landing') }}</title>
```

Porque no toma ningún valor.

Si consideran que hay una forma más apropiada de donde contener los nombres de las paginas y algunos textos recurrentes, no duden en decírmelo, se los agradeceré.

Una base de datos no es apropiada porque son muy pocos datos y no quiero alentar las conexiones por la cantidad de solicitudes que tengo.

Comment: a veces, cuando cambias o agregas algo en `.env`, la app no toma los cambios porque sigue usando los que están cacheados. probaste `php artisan config:clear` y/o `php artisan cache:clear`. Pero no sé si entendí bien la pregunta... También puedes crear una archivo con los datos en la carpeta `config` y tomarlos de ahí.

Comment: Si ya ejecute el **"php artisan config:cache"** El problema es que no se como llamar a los datos desde una vista.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con estos comandos, para asegurarte que la app no esté tomando datos cacheados en vez de los que has agregado/cambiado en el archivo .env:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

También (mejor), puedes crear un archivo `config/paginas.php` que con algo así:

```
<?php

return [
    'landing' => env('landing', 'Bienvenido a mi sitio'), //si son datos sensibles tómala el archivo .env. Además puedes poner un valor por defecto, como 'Bienvenido a mi sitio'.
    'about' => 'Sobre Nosotros', // si no es un dato sensible
    //...
];
```

y obtienes los datos con `config('paginas.landing')`, o en blade:

```
{{ config('paginas.landing') }}
{{ config('paginas.about') }}
```

Cada vez que actualices los archivos de configuración y `.env` ejecuta `php artisan config:cache` nuevamente.

Referencias:
[Accessing Configuration Values](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

> Puede acceder fácilmente a sus valores de configuración utilizando la función auxiliar global `config` desde cualquier lugar de su aplicación. Se puede acceder a los valores de configuración utilizando la sintaxis de "punto", que incluye el nombre del archivo y la opción a la que desea acceder.
> También se puede especificar un valor predeterminado y se devolverá si la opción de configuración no existe.

[Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching)

> Para darle a su aplicación un aumento de velocidad, debe almacenar en caché todos sus archivos de configuración en un solo archivo usando el comando artisan `config:cache`. Esto combinará todas las opciones de configuración para su aplicación en un solo archivo que será cargado rápidamente por el framework.
> Por lo general, debe ejecutar el comando php artisan `config:cache` como parte de su rutina de implementación de producción. El comando no debe ejecutarse durante el desarrollo local, ya que las opciones de configuración con frecuencia deberán cambiarse durante el curso del desarrollo de su aplicación.

> **NOTA Importante**: Si ejecuta el comando `config:cache` durante su proceso de implementación, debe asegurarse de que solo está llamando a la función `env` desde sus archivos de configuración. Una vez que la configuración se ha almacenado en caché, el archivo `.env` no se cargará y todas las llamadas a la función `env` devolverán un valor nulo.